# NLTK Naive Bayes Classifies error

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes

Error Message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ABHINAV/Documents/test2.py", line 58, in 
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 194, in train
    for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
[Finished in 17.0s with exit code 1]

I am getting this error while I am trying to implement Naive Bayes on a set of data. Here is the code for that:

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4


trainfeats=[('good'),('pos'),
('quick'),('pos'),
('easy'),('pos'),
('big'),('pos'),
('iterested'),('pos'),
('important'),('pos'),
('new'),('pos'),
('patient'),('pos'),
('few'),('neg'),
('bad'),('neg'),

]

test=[
('general'),('pos'),
('many'),('pos'),
('efficient'),('pos'),
('great'),('pos'),
('interested'),('pos'),
('top'),('pos'),
('easy'),('pos'),
('big'),('pos'),
('new'),('pos'),
('wonderful'),('pos'),
('important'),('pos'),
('best'),('pos'),
('more'),('pos'),
('patient'),('pos'),
('last'),('pos'),
('worse'),('neg'),
('terrible'),('neg'),
('awful'),('neg'),
('bad'),('neg'),
('minimal'),('neg'),
('incomprehensible'),('neg'),
]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test)
classifier.show_most_informative_features()
```

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**

You need to have this:

```
trainfeats=[('good','pos'),
('quick','pos'),
...
```

Instead of this:

```
trainfeats=[('good'),('pos'),
('quick'),('pos'),
...
```

---

**Explanation**

The crucial error is `ValueError: too many values to unpack` inside `NaiveBayesClassifier.train` which you call on this line:

```
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
```

'Too many values to unpack' means the program is expecting a certain number of values inside an iterable, and it's receiving more than that number. For example, from your error message that error is thrown on this line:

```
for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
```

This for loop expects *pairs* of things to be in 'labeled_featuresets', and it's going to assign one member of the pair to `featureset`, and one member to `label`. If `labeled_featuresets` actually has triplets, e.g. [(1,2,3), (1,2,3)...] then the program doesn't know what to do with that third element, so it throws the error.

Here's what you're passing into that function, which I assume is ending up as `labeled_featuresets`:

```
trainfeats=[('good'),('pos'),
('quick'),('pos'),
('easy'),('pos'),
...
```

It looks like you're trying to make a list of tuples (which would prevent the error you're getting) by indenting the items in that list as pairs, but *that's not enough*. Python won't use indentation to infer tuples, only *brackets*. I think this is what you're going for:

```
trainfeats=[('good','pos'),
('quick','pos'),
('easy','pos'),
...
```

That surrounds each pair with brackets, creating a list of tuples rather than a list of single elements.

Comment: I tried defining the tuples as you mentioned but I am still getting some errors. Here is what I am getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/test2.py", line 28, in <module>
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 196, in train
    for fname, fval in featureset.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
[Finished in 2.9s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 0):

The `trainfeat` variable should be:

```
 trainfeats=[({'good':True,'quick':True,'easy':True,
'big':True,'interested':True,'important':True,
'new':True,'patient':True},'pos'),({'few':True,'bad':True},'neg')]
```

This is the correct format for a labelled feature set in nltk.

Similarly, the test variable should be:

```
test=[({'general':True,'many':True,'efficient':True,'great':True,'interested':True,'top':True,'easy':True,'big':True,'new':True,'wonderful':True,'important':True,'best':True,'more':True,'patient':True,'last':True},'pos'),({'worse':True,'terrible':True,'awful':True,'bad':True,'minimal':True,'incomprehensible':True},'neg')]
```